# how to write .htaccess fiile for my directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

[image]I've have my website ready to be deployed .But I did not know that it was an easy task. I'm not able to understand the things to be written in .htaccess file to make my site run.

directory for my project:-

```
-MVC290916
--app
--public
--vendor
--composer.json
--composer.lock
```

here app,public and vendor are directories.

My public file contains the index.php file.
So I want to know how to write an .htaccess for my directory and the yntax details so that i will face no further problem in future.

Answer (score 0):

You don't **NEED** a .htaccess file to run your website. If there's a particular task that you want to get done such as:

- Security
- Mod_rewrite
- Custom Error Pages
- Mime Types
- SSL

Only then you have to have a .htaccess file. If not, simple upload your code on the server and that's it.

If you're facing any error while doing that, mention the exact error that you're facing.

Comment: http://52.41.195.76/

open this link....
at place of the site .... directory comes on the page.... so what should i do.

Comment: So here's what you do. Login into your server(ssh)-->cd /etc/apache2/sites-enables --> vim 000-default.conf --> Places where you see the path /var/www, change it to /var/www/html/public. This should be done in both the places. Also, do have a look first whether your server has the directory html or not before updating. Once done, save the vim file and exit and then restart your apache server (service apache2 restart)

Comment: "Also, do have a look first whether your server has the directory html or not before updating."

i didnot get this part

Comment: Some servers have the file structure as /var/www/html and some just have /var/www. Check that before changing.

Comment: i have it var/www/html

Comment: Then /var/www/html/<path to your public folder>

Comment: I hve changed it .
there was only one place to change it.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your conf file?

Comment: i ve uploaded a screenshot